# Regex end with a character or end of line with lookahead

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have this string

> Book Release Date: 2 June, 2010 [Edition#5]
>
> Book Release Date: 24 October, 1996

I want to use a regex to find the date only like follow:

> 2 June, 2010
>
> 24 October, 1996

I have tried using this pattern that is close to what I want

```
# this pattern result
# 2 June, 2010 [Edition#5]
# 24 October, 1996
date = re.findall(r"(?<=(Book Release Date: ))(.*?)(?=(\[|\n))", text)

# this pattern result
# 2 June, 2010
# None
date = re.findall(r"(?<=(Book Release Date: ))(.*?)(?=\[)", text)
```

Comment: In the first variant try to modify `.*` by adding a question mark to make it non-greedy: `.*?`

Comment: Check if this works for you
`Book Release Date: [0-9]+ (January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December), [1-9]+`
You can shorten this I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any lookaround assertions, just a single capture group that will be returned using *re.findall*

```
\bBook Release Date: (\d+ [A-Z][a-z]+, \d{4})\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bBook Release Date:`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+ [A-Z][a-z]+` Match 1+ digits, space, uppercase char A-Z, 1+ lowercase chars
  - `, \d{4}` Match `,`  and 4 digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBrLJ9/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VSNZbi)

Example

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\bBook Release Date: (\d+ [A-Z][a-z]+, \d{4})\b"
 
s = ("Book Release Date: 2 June, 2010 [Edition#5]\n"
    "Book Release Date: 24 October, 1996")
 
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['2 June, 2010', '24 October, 1996']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `:\s(\d+)\s(\w+,)\s(\d+)`, code:

```
import re

s ='''
Book Release Date: 2 June, 2010 [Edition#5]

Book Release Date: 24 October, 1996

'''

print([' '.join(i) for i in re.findall(':\s(\d+)\s(\w+,)\s(\d+)', s)])
```

Output:

```
['2 June, 2010', '24 October, 1996']
```